# Insufficient user permission performing an operation on Sql Server Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, t-sql

I am trying to re-run migration on a newly created DB in azure. DB, User, and all privileges were created from scratch. I basically granted all operation permission to the user including DB admin roles for read and write: (basically tried all these)

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_ddladmin', N'myuser'

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'myuser'
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'myuser'

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, ALTER TO myuser
```

But in the end I am still seeing error performing this specific operation. (logs from Azure DevOps)

```
2020-08-06T15:26:10.9511511Z Beginning Transaction
2020-08-06T15:26:11.0719834Z ExecuteSqlStatement ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ContextState] ALTER COLUMN [JsonContent] ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()');
2020-08-06T15:26:11.2674256Z !!! An error occured executing the following sql:
2020-08-06T15:26:11.2675116Z ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ContextState] ALTER COLUMN [JsonContent] ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()');
2020-08-06T15:26:11.2675549Z The error was User does not have permission to perform this action.
```

Comment: From [sp_addrolemember (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): *"This feature is in maintenance mode and may be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Use [**ALTER ROLE**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what extra privileges db_owner gives which was missing from what I tried above, but this fixed my problem:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'myuser'
```

I post it here hopefully it could help anyone.

Comment: A `db_owner` can do *anything* in the database apart from anything that is explicitly denied, so this permission is likely too high. You *really*, however, need to stop using `sp_addrolemember` too, like I commented; it's due to be removed from SQL Server.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for your comment, I understand your point but this is the test dev db and it doesn't expose any security risk.